# Enable Remote SSL on Weblogic

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I've enabled **SSL Listen Port** from the Admin Console of Weblogic 11g Version: 10.3.6.0

I've created a **self-signed cert** following: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/weblogic-configure-ssl-for-a-managed-server

But when try https on the browser of a remote machine I get a timeout.

If I try from the local machine using: **curl -Ik** I get the proper response, it seems that only remote access is disabled.

Accessing via http works fine from my remote machine browser. I did also try telnet but it only works with 7001 but not with 7002 (my secure port). I've already tried changing the secure port number but the result is the same.

My Weblogic server is on a Centos running on VMware ESXi.

What could be blocking the remote SSL connection?

Answer (score 0):

A timeout indicates a firewalling of some sort. As you say yourself if you try locally with curl it works. There is nothing else to check if locally you can but remotely you get a timeout.